# Making a secure rest get request

Tags: php, rest, http

Usually if I want to return some data from a server, I would make a POST request with some token inside the request body:

```
$token = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'token');
$request = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'request');
```

But what about securing GET rest api requests? I don't want to place tokens inside the URL. How should I send a security token inside a GET request?

Answer (score 1):

Place the token in the request header (for all request types,not just for GET).This is the recommended way.